# I am trying to arrange an array of Strings alphabetically using Quicksort. What are the problems with my Java method(s)?

Tags: java, arrays, string, recursion, quicksort

So I had a .csv file of around 250 unsorted names that I have put into an array of Strings. My professor wants me to sort the array alphabetically and print them out. When I print them, they are somewhat in alphabetical order but not perfectly. For example, there is the odd Y name within the Ts, or a P name in the Ns. My methods must be flawed in some way! Here they are:

```
    private static void swapper(String[] members, int i, int j) {
        String temp = members[i];
        members[i] = members[j];
        members[j] = temp;
    }
    
    private static int partitioner(String[] members, int low, int high) {
        int pivot = low;
        int leftWall = low;
        
        for(int i = low + 1; i < high; i++) {
            if(members[i].compareToIgnoreCase(members[pivot]) < 0) {
                swapper(members, i, leftWall);
                leftWall++;
            }
        }
        if (members[pivot].compareToIgnoreCase(members[leftWall]) < 0) {
            swapper(members, pivot, leftWall);
        }
        return leftWall;
    }
    
    private static void quickSort(String[] members, int low, int high) {
        if (low < high) {
           int pivotLocation = partitioner(members, low, high);
           quickSort(members, low, pivotLocation);
           quickSort(members, pivotLocation + 1, high);
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn how to use a debugger. I would suggest that you take your data set and edit it down until you have the smallest set you can find which produces an error. Maybe you can construct an example with just 5 names, where 2 are swapped in the wrong order, something like that. It may take some trial and error. Once you have a more manageable set, start stepping through your code 1 line at a time.

Comment: Then you can answer your question, and then accept the answer.